# run a query if a value on the last row is correct

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Id like to run a query only if a value in the last row is correct. In my exemple if the value in ColumnA is 1 on the last row then i want to run MyQuery. But if the value is not 1 stop there and do nothing.

i've try with case and count(*) and also with If exists. but i keep getting error

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (Select a.* from table as a order by a.index desc limit 1) as b
        where b.ColumnA = 1)) > 0 )
THEN (MyQuery)
END
```

i've also try with if exists but it doesn'work either

```
if exists Select b.* from (Select a.* from table as a order by a.index desc limit 1) where b.ColumnA = 1
begin 
(MyQuery)
end
```

can you point me what wrong in those query or maybee there's a better way to achive this.

EDIT. This query will be run on a trigger after each insert in that table the goal is to avoid running MyQuery on row that dont required it. MyQuery is a bit slow and most row dont required it to run.

Comment: The `IF` statement is allowed only in a Stored Routine.  (Else you must do it in your application code.)

Comment: Well i came to understant that my logic is wrong. i cant run any query below any query and cant use a select instead of an IF. ill have to find a better way to acheive this.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can rephrase your logic here to make it work as you want:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ColumnA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY index DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

(your query here)
WHERE (SELECT ColumnA FROM cte WHERE rn = 1) = 1;
```

The `WHERE` clause above would return either true or false, and would apply to all records in the potential result set from your query.  That is, if the `ColumnA` value from the "last" record were 1, then you would get back the entire result set, otherwise it would be empty set.

Assuming your version of MariaDB supports neither `ROW_NUMBER` nor CTEs, then use:

```
(your query here)
WHERE (SELECT ColumnA FROM yourTable ORDER BY index DESC LIMIT 1) = 1;
```

Comment: I falied to mention that im using mariadb Version 10.1, Row_Number() have been introduce in the version 10.2. ill have to think about updating but id like to avoid it at this point.

Comment: @No666 I edited my answer to give you something which should work on your version of MariaDB.

Comment: I edited my question. im not tring to filter the result of MyQuery but instead prevent MyQuery from running on row's that dont require it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your query is.

```
INSERT ...
    SELECT ... WHERE ...  -- this could lead to zero rows being inserted

DELETE ...
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ... )  -- this could lead to zero rows being deleted

UPDATE t1 JOIN t2 ...  -- the JOIN may cause no rows to be updated
```

Note:

```
(Select a.* from table as a order by a.index desc limit 1) as b
    where b.ColumnA = 1)) > 0 )
```

can be simplified (and sped up) to

```
( ( SELECT ColumnA FROM table ORDER BY index DESC LIMIT 1 ) = 1 )
```

Note that that is a true/false "expression", so it can be used in various places.